# Python: Real-time input into the microphone

Tags: python, real-time, microphone, noise-reduction

I just want to know if there is a way to input something real-time into the microphone with python. I am planning to make an open-source real-time noise cancellation app like Krisp.

Answer (score 1):

You can give [pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) a shot.

```sh
python -m pip install pyaudio
```

PyAudio example

```py
import pyaudio
import wave
 
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "your-rockstar-voice.wav"
 
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
 
# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE, input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print "recording..."
frames = []
 
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print "finished recording"
 
 
# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
 
waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
waveFile.close()
```

Comment: Can I just input your-rockstar-voice.wav straight into the microphone?

Comment: @somePythonProgrammer, haha! I'm not so sure about that one

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a solution made with python for live noise canceling problem, because I have a noisy neighbor. So, in my searches I found this Python solution:

[**rattlesnake** - A python application that does noise cancellation](https://github.com/loehnertz/rattlesnake)

As I noticed, the live mode captures noise from a microphone while playing an audio file. So, the output stream plays the audio file joining the inverted waves for canceling noise, like those ear phones that have noise canceling system.

I'm planning to create a noise canceling system using a Raspberry PI running something like this live noise canceling to create a silence zone at home. As I noticed, it requires some changes on the original code because the live mode requires a mp3 file as parameter.